# Why I have to declare each and every class in my hibernate.cfg.xml when using annotations?

Tags: java, hibernate, annotations

Why it isn't enough to set the @Entity annotation?

Am I missing the point here e.g. performance?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The annotation is not enough because hibernate does not know where your annotated classes live without some sort of explicit declaration.  It could, in theory, scan every single class in the classpath and look for the annotation but this would be very very expensive for larger projects.

You can use spring which has a helper that can allow you to specify the package(s) that your hibernate objects are in and it will just scan these packages for @Entity.  If you have all your objects in a small number of fixed packages this works well.

E.g.

```
  <bean id="referenceSessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan">
      <array>
        <value>com.xxx.hibernate.objects</value>
      </array>
    </property>
  </bean>
```

The above is the Spring declaration.  If you aren't familiar with the above syntax you can just construct it programmatically.

```
AnnotationSessionFactoryBean sfb = new AnnotationSessionFactoryBean();
sfb.setDataSource( ds );
sfb.setHibernateProperties( hibProps);
sfb.setPackagesToScan( ... );
sfb.initialise();
SessionFactory sf = sfb.getObject();
```

It supports a bunch of config options so you can use raw properties or pass in a pre-config'd datasource.

Comment: You can also use `LocalSessionFactoryBean` these days, which supports providing a `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in case you need one of those.  I'm not sure at which version of spring this gained the `setPackagesToScan` method, but it certainly has one now.

Answer (score 3):

You don't if you set `hibernate.archive.autodetection` property to `true`. There is a performance issue here as Hibernate will search the jar files for the JPA annotation. Note that, it will also initializes those classes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes :)

The `hibernate.cfg.xml` file is not used to specify your entities, it's used to configure things like hibernate's connection parameters and global settings. The `hibernate.cfg.xml` file also contains instructions on how to locate the entities. You can list the XML mapping files using `<mapping resource=XYZ>`, but if you're using JPA annotations like `@Entity`, then this is unnecessary, Hibernate will auto-detect them.

You *can* mix annotations and mapping XML if you choose, but that's by no means necessary in most situations.

Comment: "if you're using JPA annotations like @Entity, then this is unnecessary, Hibernate will auto-detect them" -- It quite clearly doesn't do so by default.  I get unregistered entity type exceptions if I do not tell it about the classes (I use `AnnotationConfiguration.addAnnotatedClass` to tell it about them programatically).  Not sure what I'm doing wrong, but this is not entirely automatic.

Answer (score 1):

> By default all properly annotated
>   classes and all hbm.xml files found
>   inside the archive are added to the
>   persistence unit configuration. You
>   can add some external entity through
>   the class element though.

[Hibernate EntityManager Reference Docs](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/entitymanager/reference/en/html/configuration.html)